# Python: what happens to base class attributes and methods when I override them? Do they still "exist"?

Tags: python, inheritance

Say I have

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
       self.x = 5
```

and I derive

```
class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
       self.x = 4
```

Now, I still want access to the original `x` in `Base` in my derived class. But I overrode it, so has it disappeared forever? Or can I still find it somewhere?

Note I cannot call my derived value of `x` something else, since methods in `Base` will call `self.x` and that `self.x` needs to be `4` if that method is called from a `Derived`-object!

The above example is for a variable, but the same question applies for a method in `Base`, overriden in `Derived`.

Comment: There is no original. Unlike C++, attributes belong solely to the instance, not the class.

Comment: Methods, by contrast, *are* class attributes, allowing you to refer to methods of an ancestor class via class names or `super` instances.

Comment: `self.x = …` programmatically assigns a value to an attribute. The attribute doesn’t “exist” outside of it. It works the same as `o = Derived(); o.x = 4`. The object cannot have two attributes of the same name. So… no.

Answer (score 0):

If you include attribute outside of init it will be a class bound parameter. This way you could access `Base.x` Thus every instance you create of derived will have `x` attribute as per init and you can access `Base` attribute.

```
>>> class Base:
...     x = 5
>>> class Derived(Base):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.x = 4
>>> derived_instance = Derived()
>>> derived_instance.x
4
>>> Base.x
5
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access ancestor attribute value you should use a `super` reference.

```
class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
       # here self.x does not exist yet
       super()._init__()
       # now self.x exists and is equal to 5
       self.x = 4
       # you have now overriden self.x
```

You can do the same thing with class methods, for instance store value return by `super().some_method(*args)` in a variable and do something else in child class.